# Use PHP inside Handlebars template

Tags: php, node.js, handlebars.js

I'm using NodeJS with Express and Handlebars for rendering my webpage. I am trying to use PHP on my webpage, is this possible with Handlebars?

When I try to use PHP in my Handlebars template file, but it seems like Handlebars can't render PHP? PHP is installed on the webserver and definitely works, but it seems inside my handlebars template, it doesn't.

When I try pasting this into my Handlebars template file: (Inside the body part)

```
<?php
echo "Test!";
?>`
```

Nothing is being displayed on the page.
When I try this:

```
<?php
echo "<p>Test!</p>";
?>
```

It displays as:
"Test!
"; ?> "
On my webpage.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it not possible to include php in my handlebars file? If so, how can I use php with handlebars?

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not work.

Unless your template file has a php extension or your web server is set to render handlebars files through a php handler. Which I doubt.

You cannot mingle front-end and back-end code.

Comment: How can I circumvent this? I am currently using nodeJs entirely for my website, and render the page with handlebars.

Comment: Why would you possibly need php in your node.js project?